# Can't set form value on a functional test

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I'm currently doing this tutorial: http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/testing-unit-and-functional-phpunit.html I'm at the "Test contact page" part.

There we have defined a test called testContact() http://pastebin.com/PtzwY7PJ (edited by me, the outcommented stuff results in the same error)

If I run the tests I get the error. InvalidArgumentException: Unreachable field "name"

If I send the form on the page I can catch if via the symfony toolbar, so I assume, the form works correctly.

Heres the dumped object of $form: http://pastebin.com/n8MyHEfy

Thanks!

Comment: did you solve this? I have the same issue on the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

the form is named 'contact' now, so you need:

```
    // Select based on button value, or id or name for buttons
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Submit')->form();

    $form['contact[name]']       = 'name';
    $form['contact[email]']      = 'email@email.com';
    $form['contact[subject]']    = 'Subject';
    $form['contact[body]']       = 'The comment body must be at least 50 characters long as there is a validation constrain on the Enquiry entity';

    $crawler = $client->submit($form);
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be like this?

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('Submit')->form(array(
        'blogger_blogbundle_enquirytype[name]' =>'name'
    ));
```